# Saving python file in virtual environment

Tags: python, powershell, nano

I'm just trying to Save a simple program, in powershell Python Nano Virtual Environment.

But I am getting an error in saving the file.

[image]

At last and final Step 6 of this blog post, where I have done 1-5 finally. program should save.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-windows-10

Why am I getting this error & how do I overcome it?

Comment: In which directory are you trying to write this file ?

Comment: (my_env) PS C:\WINDOWS\System32\Environments

Comment: I kknow, the shell is started as administrator, but can you try again in a directory like c:\tmp ?

Comment: I dont see a folder in C called tmp. Should I make such a folder,  try the virtue environment there, and see how it goes?

Comment: Yes, please try in c:\tmp or c:\temp.

Comment: I love youi!! It worked!! Yes !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may happened, because you try to write in a directory which is protected.

Try to create a directory for your project `"c:\mySources"` and create your scripts inside.